# Should XML Parser apply XSD Schema restrictions to CDATA?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xsd

I'm importing some XML files into SQL which have an XSD schema which I am validating against. The "issue" I've found is that some of the data in the files is contained within CDATA tags but the corresponding XML element is defined as an xsd:token (from W3Schools - "The token data type also contains characters, but the XML processor will remove line feeds, carriage returns, tabs, leading and trailing spaces, and multiple spaces."). What I noticed was that when I ran a simple XQuery in SQL against the Typed XML variable it was applying the xsd:token rules of removing multiple spaces to the CDATA values. Before I go back to the supplier of the file I just wanted to double check what the correct result should be. See below snippet of code...

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.MyTestSchema

AS

N'
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="ROOT">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Test" 
              minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="Test" type="TestType"/>
  <xsd:simpleType name="TestType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>'

GO

DECLARE @XMLData varchar(MAX) = 
'<ROOT>
  <Test><![CDATA[0spaces]]></Test>
  <Test><![CDATA[1 space]]></Test>
  <Test><![CDATA[2  spaces]]></Test>
  <Test><![CDATA[3   spaces]]></Test>
</ROOT>'

DECLARE @XML xml = @XMLData
DECLARE @MyTestXML xml(CONTENT dbo.MyTestSchema) = @XMLData

;WITH WithoutSchema AS
(
    SELECT [Test] = NULLIF(T2.n.value('.', 'varchar(10)'), '')
    FROM @XML.nodes('/ROOT') AS T1(n)
    CROSS APPLY T1.n.nodes('Test') AS T2(n)
),
WithSchema AS
(
    SELECT [Test] = NULLIF(T2.n.value('.', 'varchar(10)'), '')
    FROM @MyTestXML.nodes('/ROOT') AS T1(n)
    CROSS APPLY T1.n.nodes('Test') AS T2(n)
)
SELECT [WithoutSchema] = N.Test, [WithSchema] = Y.Test
FROM WithoutSchema N
INNER JOIN WithSchema Y
    ON REPLACE(N.Test, ' ', '') = REPLACE(Y.Test, ' ', '')

GO

DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.MyTestSchema

GO
```

...the results are...

```
WithoutSchema WithSchema
------------- ----------
0spaces       0spaces
1 space       1 space
2  spaces     2 spaces
3   spaces    3 spaces
```

...as you can see, using a non-typed xml variable preserves the spaces in the CDATA text, but using the typed variable (which uses xsd:token) is stripping them out. Should that be happening, I thought xsd was only applied to non-CDATA values? The spaces have a meaning in the data we are loading so if that is correct behaviour I need to raise with the supplier. I tried to read the data via C# and applying the schema to what results that gave as a comparison but my skills there a limited so didn't have much success.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems correct. In the first instance the XML is just raw data. You select raw data, you get raw data. Your data contains whitespace you get whitespace. In the second you declare your data to be of a type which explicitly normalises data -- that is the meaning of the `xsd:token` type (whitespace is collapsed, leading and trailing whitespace is removed).

An `xsd:token` type is analogous to a symbol declaration in most programming languages. It does not usually matter how many spaces you put between type and name or between name and assignment, for example in Java/C/C++ this is all valid:

```
int         a = 5; // variable is called 'a' not '        a'.
int b
= 5; // not very readable, but the variable is called 'b'.
```

As for `CDATA`: `CDATA` is just a way to instruct the XML parser to treat the characters as raw data -- but any other information/instructions still apply. So it is a more convenient way of inserting the characters `<` and `&` into an XML node; however the meaning and therefore the interpretation of the data does not change. The meaning & interpretation of data is defined by the schema, and the `CDATA` is only data (which is interpreted according to the schema).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will go back to our supplier because we receive another file (csv) with a list of "primary key" values which we should join to our XML files on the field in question. The trouble is the csv file contains double spaces in some cases which then doesn't link to the value loaded by the xml file (with their schema applied) which has turned that into just 1 space so now we are getting orphaned data :)